# Speed up view inflation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my app I have to show a calendar with a custom layout for each day. For this I use a RecyclerView with this layout manager: `new GridLayoutManager(view.getContext(), 7)` and a custom adapter. The adapter will have to inflate between 35 and 49 items (7 for the days of the week and another 4 to 6 rows of 7 items each for the days of the month). All this takes 1 second or a bit more, which is way too long, because it makes the app laggy. I've noticed that the cause for the delay is in inflating the view. Inflating a view takes between 15 and 25 milliseconds, multiply that by the +-50 views and you have a whole second. This is the code I use for inflating the view in `onCreateViewHolder`, which takes around 20 milliseconds:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(this.itemLayout, viewGroup, false);
```

Is there any way to speed this up?

---

### EDIT

Xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_monthEntries"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:overScrollMode="never"/>
```

Fragment:

```
    RecyclerView recyclerViewMonthEntries = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_monthEntries);
    this.monthEntryAdapter = new CalendarMonthEntryAdapter(view.getContext(), calendar, null, R.layout.listitem_calendar_month_entry, R.layout.listitem_calendar_month_day, recommendedRowHeight);
    this.monthEntryAdapter.setListener(this);
    recyclerViewMonthEntries.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(view.getContext(), 7));
    recyclerViewMonthEntries.setAdapter(this.monthEntryAdapter);
    recyclerViewMonthEntries.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

OnCreateViewHolder:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType)
{
    switch (viewType)
    {
        case TYPE_HEADER:
            View viewHeader = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(this.headerLayout, viewGroup, false);
            return new DayOfWeekViewHolder(viewHeader);
        case TYPE_ENTRY:
            View viewEntry = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(this.itemLayout, viewGroup, false);
            return new CalendarMonthEntryViewHolder(viewEntry);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

OnBindViewHolder:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i)
{
    switch (this.getItemViewType(i))
    {
        case TYPE_HEADER:
            this.onBindHeaderViewHolder((DayOfWeekViewHolder) viewHolder, i);
            break;

        case TYPE_ENTRY:
            this.onBindEntryViewHolder((CalendarMonthEntryViewHolder) viewHolder, i - 7);
            break;
    }
}
```

The bind is nothing special, just some setText and setVisibility. Binding takes around 1 millisecond. I put logs before and after the inflate, and that's what consumes all the time.

Comment: Please add a comment when downvoting, so I can improve my question.

Comment: Would you  provide details on your RecyclerView creation and property-setting code, adapter onCreateViewHolder, onBindViewHolder?

Comment: Try setting recycler view height to `match_parent` or any fixed height instead. Normally your adapter should lazily inflate all views, but my guesses are that:
1) wrap_content makes adapter create all the views to calculate height
2) what does adapter listens to? maybe callback event occurs to often?
3) anything heavy happens in ViewHolder constructor code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding my items one by one. I start with a count of 1, and then I add 1 to the count on the end of `onBindViewHolder`:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i)
{
    //Normal code here

    new Handler().post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            if(currentCount < maxCount)
            {
                currentCount++;
                notifyItemInserted(currentCount - 1);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Not an optimal solution I think, but it works. The items pop up on the screen one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your code, but i'd blindly recommend to use a table adapter in a linear layout.

But to develop further:

You need to make a decision. Do you need the custom views completely available after load, or you can present the calendar with some basic view format (same for all), and then customize as needed. It is a design and UX decision.

As an approach you could,

1. Load the calendar as a single view containing a table adapter.
2. Load the custom view onClick
3. Populate all table cells with the custom views after the app gets up. This is the UX design. You must decide if you simply load and present them as soon as ready. Or show some custom "spinning" animation. Or hide the entire loading effort in an animated presentation effect (present the calendar in an animated way, that will be perceived as an UX enhancement).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't completely get the idea of a table adapter. Do you mean a normal BaseAdapter for a ListView / GridView? The custom views must be available right away since they show the number of the day and have an indicator whether or not there are events for that day. But the problem remains, for each day a view must be inflated.

Comment: I sometimes forget that there is no table adapter in Android as in iOS. Indeed, it is custom made adapter to set views of table cells.

Maybe you can "hide" the loading/inflating by using an animation, as i said.

Or you can present the basic cells with numbers, then modify post-inflation indicators (possibly animated)